# jQuery, responsive design: how to change a class based on window size

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm creating a responsive magento theme but I've run into a problem. During normal window sizes the positions of my menu are different to when it's at ipad /mobile size. I want to know if there's a jQuery command that allows you to remove a class / div based on the window size, any help would be appreciated.

This following is something I tried but didn't work:

```
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        var $j = jQuery;
        var windowwidth = $j(window).width();

        $j(windowwidth).onChange(function(){
            if (windowwidth < '148') {
                $j('.parent').css('display','relative');
            }
        });
    }
```

Couldn't get the jQuery to work as suggested below the css3 method works perfectly. 
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {}

Comment: Did you try CSS media queries instead of doing it in JavaScript? F.ex. http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/responsive-layouts-using-css-media-queries/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put an event listener on a number (`windowwidth`). You just need to compare that value with the desired one from the `resize` event handler.

The `resize` handler will fire each time the window's width or height changes.

Your code should look like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 148) {
        $('.parent').css('display','relative');
    }
}
```

You should also look into using [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) instead of JS for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can either do it the way dcro says, with the resize event handler and the windowwidth, or you could also do it in CSS with the @media tag by creating a condition like this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {}
```

source : http://line25.com/tutorials/create-a-responsive-web-design-with-media-queries

the @media tag might not work on older browsers though

Answer (score 1):

I advice to look jRespond jquery library for this type of jobs.

https://github.com/ten1seven/jRespond

ex:

```
var jRes = jRespond([
        {
            label: 'small',
            enter: 0,
            exit: 1000
        },{
            label: 'desktop',
            enter: 1001,
            exit: 10000
        }
    ]);


    jRes.addFunc({
        breakpoint: 'small',
        enter: function() {
           $('#sidebarbg,#sidebar,#content').removeClass('hided');
        },
        exit: function() {
           $('.collapseBtn.top.hide').removeClass('top hide');
        }
    });
```

Its binding event to the defined window sizes to trigger the written function.

Comment: I will take a look at jRespond in the future this is my first time doing responsive so for the next project I will defo look at it. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

This would work though:

```
$(window).resize(function() {

    var windowwidth = $(window).width();

    if (windowwidth < '148') {
       $('.parent').css('display','relative');
       alert('see it works');
    }

});
```